# Killing a thread running an audio file in a service

Tags: android, multithreading, service, kill

In Android,
I am running a service that spawns a thread. The thread plays a wave audio file.
Once the completion of the audio file, I want to kill (destroy) the service.
So I wrote the following snippet for that

```
Thread  tr = new Thread() {
@Override
 public void run() {

    File path = android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    try{
    mp.setDataSource(path + "/AudioRecorder/123.wav");
    mp.prepare();
    }
    catch (Exception e){}
    mp.start();
    mp.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        stopSelf();
        }
    });
}
}   ;
tr.start();
        }
```

Note that I wrote *stopself()* to kill the service once the audio file is completed.
My question is do I need to kill the thread as well? or it will be automatically terminated once I call stopself()? If not, is it necessary to kill this thread and how can I do that and where should I add it?

Comment: you should not kill the thread (you should never kill or stop a thread -> release the thread)  it will exit itself after stopSelf is called

Comment: calling tr.setDeamon(true) will ensure you that the thread wil be released when application is exited